# Многократное использование секции с if

Tags: c++, функции, логика, рефакторинг

В ходе теста, после больших блоков проверяю, не была ли нажата кнопка СТОП.
Есть такая секция с if

```
if (m_stopTest)
{        
    manualStopTest(); // Выключаем все
    //...
    return;           // Выходим из теста
}
```

Можно ли как-то правильно оформить, данную секцию, например, в функцию, чтоб менять то, что вложено в одном месте? Например, мысли такие

```
if (checkStop(m_stopTest)) return;
```

Где `checkStop` в себя включает все те проверки и вызовы. Но тогда не логично, что `checkStop` проверяет, и еще что-то там включает, выключает.

Comment: Мутно излагаете как-то, несмотря на наличие принятого ответа. Мне скорее показалось, что вам надо функцию передать внутри, а не флаг.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я предположил, что можно сделать так, как в принятом ответе и пока так и сделал. Но думал может есть более устоявшиеся решения. Мне важно не повторять один и тот же блок if многократно, а как-то его завернуть во что-то. Но при этом должен быть return из вышестоящей функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотите что-то такое?

```
bool checkStop(bool m_stopTest)
{
    if (m_stopTest) 
    {
        manualStopTest();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Да, но вот просто кажется не логичным скрывать под именем checkStop другие функции, которые не относятся к слову check..

Comment: @ДмитрийСуворов, назови `doStopIfNeeded()`.

Comment: @ДмитрийСуворов Выбор имени - за вами :) Компилятор примет даже `fa6sd7tfgsd67sdagds76()`...

Answer (score 0):

Для решения вашей проблемы "прокидывания" `return` в вышестоящую функцию я вижу, как минимум, три варианта:

1. Использовать функцию-предикат и передавать в неё подходящий параметр: флаг (как это продемонстрировал Harry в своём ответе) или даже дополнительно функцию, которую нужно выполнить, типа `manualStopTest`:

   ```
   using F = void (*)();

   bool checkStop(bool stop, F f)
   {
       if (stop) 
       {
           f();
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

   Использование:

   ```
   if (checkStop(m_stopTest, &manualStopTest)) return;
   ```

В этом случае `return` как бы передаётся по цепочке: `return true;` внутри `checkStop` приводит к `return` из функции верхнего уровня.

2. Использовать макроподстановку:

   ```
   #define COND_RET(cond) \
   if ((cond))            \
   {                      \ 
       manualStopTest();  \
       return;            \
   }
   ```

   Пример:

   ```
   // какие-то действия ...
   COND_RET(m_stopTest)
   ```

В этом случае `return` один единственный, то это скорее C-стиль, нежели C++. Лучше избегать макросов, если в языке есть подходящие замены. В данном случае `inline` реализация функции из п.1 будет смотреться лучше.

3. Выкинуть исключение во вложенной функции и поймать его уже где-то выше:

   ```
   void checkStop(bool stop, F f)
   {
       if (stop) 
       { 
           f();
           throw stopRequested();
       }
   }
   ```

   Использование:

   ```
   // Код высшего уровня 
   try {
       // Вызов кода верхнего уровня, т.е. функции, содержащей вызов checkStop
   }
   catch(...) {
       // Нужная обработка, может быть просто игнорирование
   }
   ```

   Такой вариант я тем не менее всё равно не стал бы советовать, т.к. использовать исключения для ветвления логики не принято. Как из-за лишнего оверхеда, так и по самой идеологии исключений, которые созданы для разруливания действительно исключетельных ситуаций.